# CakePhP Linking

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink

hi all I have a cakephp page, when you hover over a link it displays the correct link however when you click the link it takes you to a completely different/wrong page.

i assume its an error with my view, so I'll include the relevant part of the site here, what is happening is the `add link` is taking users to `fields/view` NOT `fields/add_new`

```
        <tr>
                <td align='center'><?php echo $templates['Template']['name'] ;?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templates['Template']['description']; ?> </td>
                <td align='center'>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->Html->link('Add', array('controller' => 'Fields','action'=>'add_new',$templates['Template']['id'])); ;?> |
                    <?php echo $this->Form->Html->link('View', array('controller' => 'Fields','action'=>'view',$templates['Template']['id'])); ;?> |
                    <?php echo $this->Form->Html->link('Edit', array('controller' => 'Templates','action'=>'edit',$templates['Template']['id'])); ;?> |
                    <?php echo $this->Form->Html->link('Delete', array('controller' => 'Templates','action'=>'delete',$templates['Template']['id'])); ;?></td> 
         <tr>





function add_new($id=null){
        //allows users to add another field to an existing template
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Fields');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
        $this->layout='home_layout';


        if(($this->Field->save($this->request->data)))
        {

        $id = $this->data['Field']['template_id'];

        $this->set('id',$id);
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Fields', 'action'=>'view',$id));

        }
            $this->set('id',$id);
        }
```

Comment: :Share here your controller code

Comment: I've realized its automatically redirecting the page. I'll update the controller code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function add_new($id=null){
        //allows users to add another field to an existing template
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Fields');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
        $this->layout='home_layout';


        //this sets the parameter as a variable 
        $this->set('id', $id);
        //if the data posts to the databse
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            //creates an instance of field in the database
            $this->Field->create(); 
            //if the field saves to the database
            if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data))
            {   //if the user clicks this button
                $id = $this->data['Field']['template_id'];

                $this->set('id',$id);
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Fields', 'action'=>'view',$id));


            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `link` function is part of the `HtmlHelper` class.  So you need to remove the `->Form` from your function call to:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Add', array('controller' => 'fields', 'action'=>'add_new',$templates['Template']['id'])); ;?>
```

Also, Cake conventions call for the controller name to be lowercase, so specify your controller as:

`('controller' => 'fields',`

and not

`('controller' => 'Fields',`

Comment: Maybe also try getting rid of the extra semi colons in your PHP tags.  Ie, try removing the semi colon from `;?>`.